# Search query parameter is ignored in BOX REST API

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to make a call to the method search with restsharp in VS2013. Box is  ignoring the `subquery` string. I have consulted the documentation and I tested the call with "PostMan" and it works well.

```
        string query = "asterisk";
        string subquery = "file_extensions=docx";

        var client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
        client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(DEV_ACCESS_TOKEN, "Bearer");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.Resource = "search?query={query}&{subquery}";
        request.AddParameter("query", query, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.AddParameter("subquery", subquery, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;            

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the entire `file_extensions=docx` string as a URL parameter. RestSharp is URL-encoding the `=` and Box is ignoring the malformed string.

`GET /2.0/search?query=asterisk&file_extensions%3Ddocx`

The following change will produce the correct result:

```
string subquery = "docx";
request.Resource = "search?query={query}&file_extensions={subquery}";
request.AddParameter("subquery", subquery, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```

`GET /2.0/search?query=asterisk&file_extensions=docx`

Comment: It's true!! It's a silly mistake XD!! Thank you very much for your help